# Mysql - delete error :subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID = 22;
```

I was trying to delete a product using the query above and I got the error message:

Subquery returns more than 1 row

I have tried to use mysql workbrench to delete the product, still return the same error. Is this mysql bug?

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: Check for any associated trigger to product table

Comment: nope, doesn't have any trigger involved

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID = 22 LIMIT 1;
```

And also be sure that your **ID** incremented automatically.

Comment: May you take a screenshot of your Table structure ? And also select products where their id is between **20** and **23** ?